# "InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type." when loading serialized data

Tags: c#, serialization, save, loading

I'd sincerely appreciate if you looked through some of my code as I can't seem to be able to fix it myself, and this will also hopefully help others understand serialization better.

I have four pieces of related code here, with anything seemingly irrelevant cut out. I'm trying to create a user profile in a set up where the user then chooses from a range of games to play. Only options/settings for the chosen games, in this case something to do with a fish, are saved.

The error in the title occurs in the 4th section [feel free to skip to that] which is the  OptionsController.LoadOptions() function at

```
FishData.Store data = (FishData.Store)bf.Deserialize(fileOpt);
```

I have this at the top of all following sections:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
```

1) Profile data structure:

```
public class Profile {                                   //Profile variables

    public static string id;
    public static string name;
    public static string dob;
    public static bool fishEnabled;
    public static bool birdEnabled;

    public static string stringTest;


    [System.Serializable]
    public class Store {                                   //Profile variables

        public string id;
        public string name;
        public string dob;
        public bool fishEnabled;
        public bool birdEnabled;

        public string stringTest;

    }   
}
```

2) Fish data structure:

```
 public class FishData {                                   //static Fish variables to be used in game

    public static bool sizeInc;
    public static bool speedInc;
    public static int level;
    public static bool toxic;
    public static bool handLeft;

    public static bool timer;
    public static int timerVal;
    public static int percentReq;
    public static int successReq;

    public static string testStringTwo;

    public static List<StatController.Session> sessions = new List<StatController.Session>();


    [System.Serializable]
    public class Store {                               //non static variable set for serialization

        public bool sizeInc;
        public bool speedInc;
        public int level;
        public bool toxic;
        public bool handLeft;

        public bool timer;
        public int timerVal;
        public int percentReq;
        public int successReq;

        public string testStringTwo;

        public List<StatController.Session> sessions = new List<StatController.Session>();
    }

}
```

3) The script where the data file was initially created and where there didn't seem to be problems:

```
public class ProfileController : MonoBehaviour {


    public static string currentID;

    //create ----
    public InputField idField;
    public InputField nameField;
    public InputField dobField;
    public Toggle fishToggle;
    public Toggle birdToggle;

    //open ------
    public Button idTitleButton;
    public Text nameText;
    public Text dobText;

    public Text testText;
    public InputField numField;



    void Save() { //saves new ID and declares required variables based on game choice

        Debug.Log("id =" + idField.text + ", name = " + nameField.text + ", save");
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + idField.text + ".dat");

        Profile.Store data = new Profile.Store();                 //sets Profile variables

        currentID = idField.text;

        data.id = idField.text;
        data.name = nameField.text;
        data.dob = dobField.text;
        data.fishEnabled = fishToggle.isOn;
        data.birdEnabled = birdToggle.isOn;

        Profile.id = idField.text;
        Profile.name = nameField.text;
        Profile.dob = dobField.text;
        Profile.fishEnabled = fishToggle.isOn;
        Profile.birdEnabled = birdToggle.isOn;



        bf.Serialize(file, data);                            //saves Profile variables

        if (fishToggle.isOn) {
            FishData.Store dataFish = new FishData.Store();              //sets default Fish variables

            dataFish.sizeInc = false;
            dataFish.speedInc = false;
            dataFish.level = 5;
            dataFish.toxic = true;
            dataFish.handLeft = false;

            dataFish.timer = false;
            dataFish.timerVal = 240;
            dataFish.percentReq = 0;
            dataFish.successReq = 0;

            bf.Serialize(file, dataFish);                   //saves default Fish variables

            Debug.Log("level = " + dataFish.level);



        }

        file.Close();                                         //closes save file

        idSelectField.text = idField.text;          //ensures current ID is used as selected ID where needed
        EnableOpenProfile();                                   //loads new profile

    }


    void Load() {


        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + idField.text + ".dat")) {  //loads save file
            currentID = idField.text;
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + idField.text + ".dat", FileMode.Open);
            Profile.Store data = (Profile.Store)bf.Deserialize(file);

            nameField.text = data.name;                             //loads saved Profile details and settings
            fishToggle.isOn = data.fishEnabled;
            birdToggle.isOn = data.birdEnabled;

            fishPlayButton.enabled = data.fishEnabled;
            birdPlayButton.enabled = data.birdEnabled;


            FishData.Store dataFish = (FishData.Store)bf.Deserialize(file);     //loads saved Fish settings
            FishData.sizeInc = dataFish.sizeInc;
            FishData.speedInc = dataFish.speedInc;
            FishData.toxic = dataFish.toxic;
            FishData.timer = dataFish.timer;
            FishData.level = dataFish.level;
            FishData.timerVal = dataFish.timerVal;
            FishData.percentReq = dataFish.percentReq;
            FishData.successReq = dataFish.successReq;
            FishData.handLeft = dataFish.handLeft;



            file.Close();                                           //closes save file


            nameText.text = "Name : " + data.name + "     ID : " + data.id;     //displays profile details
            dobText.text = "DOB : " + data.dob;


        }
        else return;
    }

}
```

4) The main script that produces the error when trying to load what was saved in the previous script:

```
    public class OptionsController : MonoBehaviour {

    public static bool handLeft = false;     

    public Toggle sizeIncToggle;
    public Toggle speedIncToggle;
    public Toggle toxicToggle;
    public Toggle timerToggle;

    public Toggle leftToggle;
    public Toggle rightToggle;

    public InputField levelField;
    public InputField timerValField;
    public InputField percentReqField;
    public InputField successReqField;


    void LoadOptions() {

        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + ProfileController.currentID + ".dat")) {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream fileOpt = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + ProfileController.currentID + ".dat", FileMode.Open);

            FishData.Store data = (FishData.Store)bf.Deserialize(fileOpt); //[[ERROR HERE]]

            sizeIncToggle.isOn = data.sizeInc;
            speedIncToggle.isOn = data.speedInc;
            toxicToggle.isOn = data.toxic;
            timerToggle.isOn = data.timer;
            levelField.text = data.level.ToString();
            timerValField.text = data.timerVal.ToString();
            percentReqField.text = data.percentReq.ToString();
            successReqField.text = data.successReq.ToString();

            fileOpt.Close();

        }
    }



    public void SaveOptions() {

        Debug.Log("name = " + ProfileController.currentID + ", save");
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + ProfileController.currentID + ".dat");

        FishData.Store data = new FishData.Store();

        data.sizeInc = FishData.sizeInc;
        data.speedInc = FishData.speedInc;
        data.toxic = FishData.toxic;
        data.timer = FishData.timer;
        data.level = FishData.level;
        data.timerVal = FishData.timerVal;
        data.percentReq = FishData.percentReq;
        data.successReq = FishData.successReq;
        data.handLeft = FishData.handLeft;


        bf.Serialize(file, data);

        Debug.Log("level = " + FishData.level);

        file.Close();

    }

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure you are serializing/deserializing in the correct order it is best that you create a "holding" class which contains both a `Fish.Store` variable and `Profile.Store` variable. If you serialize and deserilize in different orders you will run into issues like trying to deserialize a `Fish.Store` object to `Profile.Store`.

Try creating another class with public variables of `Fish.Store` and `Profile.Store`, like:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public Fish.Store FishStore;
    public Profile.Store ProfileStore;

    public ExampleClass()
    {
    }
}
```

Then do:

```
ExampleClass example = new ExampleClass();
example.ProfileStore = data;
example.FishStore = dataFish;

//File Create stuff, etc
bf.Serialize(file, example);
//File close stuff, etc
```

And to deserialize:

```
ExampleClass e = (ExampleClass)bf.Deserialize(fileOpt);
data = e.ProfileStore;
dataFish = e.FishStore;
```

If you only wish to serialize/deserialize one class at a time, it is best practice to read/write to/from one file per serialized class.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. May I know why FishStore and ProfileStore have been capitalized at the beginning? Aren't instances of classes supposed to be declared with lowercase letters, as with example and e? I don't quite see the difference here.

Comment: Because I was typing it out quick and it frankly doesn't matter, it still works. You are not going to call the class `ExampleClass` it is only as an example, call it whatever you want.

Comment: I see. Using your method, will I be able to resave the data in FishStore multilpe times without affecting ProfileStore at all? Because I was testing out serializing and deserializing the two types in sequence just now by simply adding "Profile.Store dataProf = new Profile.Store(); bf.Serialize(file, dataProf);" before "FishData.Store data = new FishData.Store();" in script 4. This seemed to work fine until I saw that the profile variables were now blank and needed to be reinitialized between the two new lines I added.

Comment: Your `ExampleClass` will always have variables for `Fish.Store` and `Profile.Store`. They will always need to be the correct, current values, before serializing. Do not serialize the 2 classes seperately. Only serialize the "holding" `ExampleClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems you first save Profile.Store
and then you save FishData.Store.

Then on the load you try to retreive the FishData.Store when the Profile.Store is first in the file.

(I'm assuming you use the load from script 4 and the save in script 3.)

Comment: Both Profile.Store and FishData.Store are actually saved into the file with script 3. I have checked this manually by examining the text file - though the format is messed up due to serialization, I can clearly see variables from both present. Can you recommend a better way of saving and loading different types of data in one file?

Comment: This is a viable method, you just have to make sure you load the objects in the same order as you saved them, in this case first profile and then fishdata. At the moment when you're retreiving the fisdata you're actually retreiving the serialized profiledata. If you don't want/need to load the profiledata you could save them in seperate files. Like "fishdata" + currentID.

Comment: You could also reference your FishData.Store as a member of the ProfileData.Store, since they are meant to be serialized at the same time and FishData is serializable, then only deserialize the whole file as a ProfileData.Store object.

Comment: Casper - Oh my goodness, that was so insanely simple. Thank you so much. I added this just before the initial problem line of code: "Profile.Store dataProf = (Profile.Store)bf.Deserialize(fileOpt);"

Comment: Does this mean I also have to serialize the different data types in sequence when saving, even if I am not changing any of their variables?

Comment: Tiesselune - is this still viable in situations where I only want to serialize part of the class? I have done it this way for situations where the user never wants to play the Fish game and may want data from other games saved instead.

Comment: Serialized files can only be read/written in order so you cant query them for a specific class. anothershrubery posted a good way to handle this with allot of classes, as long as there aren't any huge files.

Comment: Purely to minimize refactoring, I was testing out serializing and deserializing the two types in sequence just now by adding "Profile.Store dataProf = new Profile.Store(); bf.Serialize(file, dataProf);" before "FishData.Store data = new FishData.Store();" in script 4. This seemed to work fine until I saw that the profile variables were now blank and needed to be reinitialized between the two new lines I added. Even if I only used one data type, would this always be the case in serialization, where the file is essentially rewritten and variables need to be reinitialized...?

Comment: Yes, generally serialized files are written in a whole, so you'd have to load all the data you'd want to rewrite. This could be done by loading everything as you start the game even if you don't need it, so in case you do change it, you change the loaded values and can just rewrite them back without losing anything in the class. Alternatively you could check for the position in the stream of the class you want to change(start and end) as its being read and then update(truncate/write)that part of the file. But thats probably more work and easier to mess up.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept anothershrubery's answer as it offers the better technical solution, but you have been so helpful to my understanding and I really appreciate that.